# iOS: How to prevent the splash screen from showing when the app goes into background to make a call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, splash-screen

The app that I'm working on is automatically showing the splash screen only when it goes into background to make a call.

The other functions of going out of the app and becoming active again does not "activate" the splash screen. For example, going out of the app into an external website, phone map or another application and coming back into the app will show user the previous state and does not show the splash screen.

Is this something that can be controlled by the app side or is this an iOS feature that apple automatically handles when a phone call is made?

I have managed the leaks on the app side and all is good now so it can't be anything to do with memory management on the app side. Is there anything else that can be done indirectly so that the splash screen will not show?

Comment: I think the Apple guides used to recommend programmatically changing the splash screen to a screenshot of the last loaded view. If you want to show the splash again later, change it back to the original image on a proper unload.

Comment: Hi Austin, I'm trying to prevent the splash screen from showing when the app comes out of background and become active. It's not a consistent behaviour as it's only showing when app exits to make a phone call and comes back:(

Comment: The launch image is not a "splash screen". The launch image is used to prevent show a black screen while the app is loaded, and you should use with an in-app screen which gives the feeling of a quick launch. If you don't show the launch image, you will get a black screen.

Comment: Hi Luis! Thanks for the reply! I'm wondering if has it got to do with the memory allocation of the phone when user makes a phone call? The launch image is only shown after a phone call and not when user comes out of background after accessing other applications, website or phone map.

Comment: @AustinMullins you can not do what you do suggest. I know it because I have already tried it, and it's not possible. Neither working with links instead of files. I think there was a way in previous iOS versions, but not anymore.

Comment: I was talking about doing what Luis said. Sorry about the botched wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The launch image is not a "splash screen". The launch image is used to prevent show a black screen while the app is loaded, and **you should use it with an in-app screen** which gives the feeling of a quick launch. If you don't show the launch image, you will get a black screen.

### Workaround

So, as workaround, my suggestion is that you take an static snapshot of your App, something generic (like the background and toolbars) and use it as launch images. This will give the appearance that the app start immediately, without "splash image". This is what Apple apps do, you can see this in apps like Stocks or Settings.

[image]

You see?. The left screen is how your launch image should look.

Check this Apple documentation [iOS Human Interface guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5) to understand this subject.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Luis, thanks for the answer. Looks like a good shoot and I'll try it out! Thanks so much once again!